# Sending an email using ajax and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send an email using Ajax and jquery but even though the Ajax request gets successful, the email is not sent. The email system works for other things but not for the reply system I am making... My code is as below:

```
var message =  $('#message').val();
var dataString = 'message=' + message ;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "reply.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
        // success function
    }
});
```

the ajax calls become successful and the success function is called but the email is not sent .. the php code is as below

```
$title = "something";
$message =  $_POST['message'];
$email = demo@demo
mail($email, "Reply to \"".$title."\"", $message,
"From: \"Ad reply\" <auto-reply@$host>\r\n" .
"X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());
```

and I have done the ... `if(isset($_POST))` thing as well.

Comment: Did you try sending your email without the Ajax part first? To ensure that your call to the mail() function is working as expected!

Comment: Your assignment to `$email` is missing quotes. Is it correct in the real code? Is your Javascript properly URL-encoding `message` (I recommend using a map instead of a string with `$.ajax`, so jQuery will take care of this)?

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not show where $host is set. Could be a malformed "from" address that is causing it?

On another not, it is not a good idea to send post data directly from a form into an email, you should run it through some filters first to ensure no nasty code can end up in the email.

Comment: it is passed through filters , m not that stupid . I just didn't wrote that up . n @host is set there but it doesn't make a difference as its just working as a string above

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for sure this will work -

**PHP CODE:**

```
if(isset($_GET['email'])){

$email = $_GET['email'];
$message = $_GET['msg'];

$to = "demo@example.com";
$subject = "Demo email";

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From:' .$email. "\r\n";            
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
echo'success';
}
else{ echo'error'; }
```

**AJAX/JQUERY SCRIPT :**

```
email = $("#email").val();
msg = $("#msg").val();
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajxContact.php?email='+email+'&msg='+msg,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
    if(html == 'error'){
        alert("An error occurer and the message can't be sent.");
      }
    else {
        alert('Email has been successfully sent.');
      }
    }
});
```